# MySQL UPDATE with GROUP and ORDER

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to make an update on a table so that it can increment the values on 1 column depending on another's order. 
Here's how it'd go

```
 ID    GROUP_ID    ORDER(Desired)   ORDER(NOW)
 1        1             1              2
 2        1             2              3
 3        1             3              1
 4        2             1              2
 5        2             2              1
 6        3             1              1
 7        3             2              1
 8        3             3              2
```

So what I need is for each ID, to update the ORDER column so it can be consecutive, starting from 1, within each GROUP_ID.

I have found some solutions to similar problems regarding the updates and orders, but none that uses multiple orders for groups within the same table.

Hope I illustrated the problem right. Thanks in advance

Comment: There's really no point storing something like this.

Comment: Actually, It´s not exactly an order, I put it that way so i could illustrate, They are actually billings, and credit cards require me to count the number of billed month within a particular service

Comment: It's still derived data. There's still no point storing it.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. Each ID is a bill, and each group is a service number, which generates billings each month. I get that it could be taken as derived data, but certainly needs a chronological order. Maybe the design itself is wrong, can you tell me hoy would you do it?

Comment: Yes. But you already have a chronology.

Comment: How are you determining the order? Is it by `ID`? (which is probably a mistake, since you probably want to order by a date/time and an `ID` is not the same, even if it's auto-incrementing). However you are ordering the data, you can calculate that order # at run time. Storing it in the DB is just going to create calculated data that will eventually get out of sync and cause more headaches than you think you're solving.

Comment: @TomH How is an auto-incrementing id 'not the same'?

Comment: I understand you point Tom, thank you for the insight

Comment: `INSERT INTO Orders (order_date) VALUES ('2016-03-10')
INSERT INTO Orders (order_date) VALUES ('2016-03-08')`
That's just one of many ways that using an auto-incrementing ID as a surrogate date/time value can cause problems.

Comment: @TomH OK, but I think we're talking here about the date that the data is added to the table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it by "ranking" the rows over again. Mysql doesn't support window functions but you can achieve the same results with join and count like this:

```
UPDATE YourTable t
INNER JOIN(SELECT s.id,s.group_id,count(*) as cnt
           FROM YourTable s
           INNER JOIN YourTable ss 
            ON(s.group_id = ss.group_id and s.id >= ss.id)
           GROUP BY s.id,s.group_id) tt
 ON (t.id = tt.id and t.group_id = tt.group_id)
SET t.order = tt.cnt
```

Comment: Thank you sagi, this worked like a charm, but I'm trying to understand where it came from. Can you try and explain a little bit about it?